# Application of NLP in Modern retail organisation by people who don't know programming

Tags: image, text, analysis

I am from a Modern retail organisation. Don't have programming knowledge. Can I use your NLP tool to process  unstructured text, data and pictures

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what tool are you referring by 'your NLP tool' ?

Google has NLP API that derives insights from unstructured text. You can get details about this API from - https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/